# Pycharm on windows server open one more window

Tags: pycharm

My OS is windows server 2012, I log in windows server twice with the same account at the same time.

Now I can only open one pycharm window. I have tried to search this problem on pycharm support, and could not find a solution.

The problem is described as follow. I can not open pycharm on window B.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

try these two steps:

> 1.Open a project, while another one is already open.
>
> 2.Depending on the selected behavior: If the option Open project in a new window is selected, PyCharm Edu will silently open new project in
>   a new window.

and check following link based on Jetbrains website:
[Opening Multiple Projects](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/opening-multiple-projects.html)

Comment: My problem is that I can not open pycharm on two login windows. The tow windows use the same account. In this condition, only one window can open pycharm. I try to open pycharm on another window, but nothing happened.